# Rounding items within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, rounding

I'm trying to round specific items within lists to different decimal places. For example, I'm trying to round the first number to 5 decimal places and the second number to 4 decimal places. So far I have this but I can't figure out how to iterate it over each list within the list.

```
round_test = []
test = [['start, 0.2222195726, 0.3332746298, 2, 'end'], ['start, 0.4444393872, 0.5554983, 2, 'end'], ['start, 0.6666559246, 0.777692366, 2, 'end']]
for start, starttime, endtime, amt, end in test:
    starttime_5 = round(starttime,5)
    endtime_4 = round(endtime,4)
    round_test = [[start, starttime_5, endtime_4, amt, end]]
print(round_test)
```

My current output is

```
[['start', 0.66666, 0.7777, 2, 'end']]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
[['start, 0.22222, 0.3333, 2, 'end'], ['start, 0.44444, 0.5555, 2, 'end'], ['start, 0.66666, 0.7777, 2, 'end']]
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Another, nested loop

Comment: you need to `append` to `round_test` as opposed to overwriting it's values every loop. the reason your output is wrong is because you overwrite every loop so your results end up being the last list in the `test` variable

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It's the classic "overwriting the result every iteration" issue, I can't see it being any more useful this time than the dozens of times it has come up before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small errors.

(1) start should be in quotes i.e. 'start' rather than 'start

(2) round_test.append(...) rather than round_test = ...

```
round_test = []
test = [['start', 0.2222195726, 0.3332746298, 2, 'end'], ['start', 0.4444393872, 0.5554983, 2, 'end'], ['start', 0.6666559246, 0.777692366, 2, 'end']]
for start, starttime, endtime, amt, end in test:
    starttime_5 = round(starttime,5)
    endtime_4 = round(endtime,4)
    round_test.append([start, starttime_5, endtime_4, amt, end])
print(round_test)
```

**Output**

```
[['start', 0.22222, 0.3333, 2, 'end'], 
 ['start', 0.44444, 0.5555, 2, 'end'], 
 ['start', 0.66666, 0.7777, 2, 'end']]
```

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you!

Comment: @Abuvavg--glad to help.